# Mysql - db-select with several joins and tablestructure

Tags: mysql, join

I am using the following mysql select-query with several joins. I am wondering if this is how a somewhat good select-statement should look like:

```
SELECT * 

FROM table_news AS a
  INNER JOIN table_cat AS b ON a.cat_id = b.id
  INNER JOIN table_countries AS c ON a.country_id = c.id
  INNER JOIN table_addresses AS d ON a.id = d.news_id

WHERE a.deleted = 0 
  AND a.hidden = 0 
  AND a.cat_id = ".$search_cat." 
  AND a.country_id =   ".$search_country." 
  AND a.title LIKE '%".$search_string."%' 
   OR a.deleted = 0 
  AND a.hidden = 0 
  AND a.cat_id = ".$search_cat." 
  AND a.country_id = ".$search_country." 
  AND a.subtitle LIKE '%".$search_string."%'"
```

It seems to be a lot of joins. Even though table b and table c contain only 3 or 4 fields, I wonder if the number of joins would clearly slow down the search on the starting-page?

Would it be better to put the fields from table d (street, city and so on) back into the main-table, as they should be needed most of the time this query is executed?

Thanx in advance,
Jayden

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is necessarily anything wrong with having three joins. There are a couple of things you can do to make sure the query is optimised.

Firstly, you should never do SELECT * - instead explicitly state what fields you want to return from the database.

Also, I would create indexes on all the fields you have in the where clause, and all of the fields you are joining. This can be a little bit of a trade off - for example if you are doing a lot of write operations then there is a hit because you need to write to the index everytime.

Comment: thank you christoph. its good to hear, that the query seems to be ok, even though i still wonder, if splitting off the address-fields from the main-table, is making lot of sense?! respective indizes, i allready added an index to field "news_id" of the addresses-table, which is corresponding with the field "id" of the main-table. after adding, mysql handles indizes automatically right?